# center align button on page

Tags: html, css

This question seems common but I'm having problems doing it right. I got 3 buttons. I've used `float: left;` and `float: right;` for 2 of them to align to the right and left. My problem is how do I align the 3rd button to the center (on the page)?

I tried `text-align: center;` , `margin: 0 auto;` , `left:0; right: 0;` but no success.

Comment: can you please show your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `text-align: center;` on the parent element.

```css
#a { float: left; }
#c { float: right; }
#parent { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <button id="a">A</button>
  <button id="b">B</button>
  <button id="c">C</button>
</div>
```

The reasons your tried solutions didn't quite work:

- As said above, `text-align` is something to be set on a parent/container element;
- The `margin: 0 auto` approach is more useful for non-inline elements with a given width;
- Setting explicit `left` and `right` will only work if you `position` them accordingly, but will be a hassle to use for centering because you set the element's left side (and not its center point), I'd not recommend that approacht for centering.

Some alternatives you may be interested in checking out include using `flexbox` (but only if you need to support modern browsers only), or using table display (probably in combination with some additional container elements around your buttons).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- html markup -->

    <div class="btn_wrap">
    <a class="btn_left">button1</a>
    <a class="btn_right">button2</a>
    <a class="btn_center">button3</a>
    </div>

/*    stylesheets */

    .btn_wrap{
    text-align:center;
    }
    .btn_left{ float:left;}
    .btn_right{ float:right;}
```

Comment: thanks. That works, but it's same as Jeroen's answer.